# Solving a differential equation with wronskians

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

So I am asked to find a solution to this ODE here and I feel like I am missing something very obvious.

I am asked to find the general solution of:

$x^2y"-3xy'+4y=\frac{x^2}{ln(x)}, y>1$

So I first tried to find the homogeneous solution which was just a cauchy Euler equation:

$x^2y"-3xy'+4y=0$

if I solve that, I get $y_{h}(x)=c_1 x^2 + c_2 x^2 ln(x)$

Then I tried to use variation of parameters to solve the particular solution. I obtain:

$W=\begin{bmatrix}
  x^2 & x^2\ln(x) \\
 2x & x+2x\ln(x) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

The wronskian ends up becoming $W=x^3$ so things worked out really nicely.

If I try to find the particular solution though, I can't integrate one of the integrals.

$Y_p(t)=-y_1\int \frac{y_2g(x)}{W}+y_2\int \frac{y_1g(x)}{W} dx$

$Y_p(t)=-x^2\int x dx +x^2\ln(x)\int \frac{x}{ln(x)} dx$

but the second integral can't be done so either I made a mistake or there is another way to solve this.

I can't even use Laplace transforms since I don't have initial conditions so I am a little lost here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you made a mistake.
Note that the coefficient of $y''$ in your differential equation is $x^2$, but you're using a formula intended for a d.e. where the coefficient of $y''$ is $1$.

Comment: How would I go about doing this then? The only way I can see in my set of notes is if I was given two fundamental sets of solutions to this equation which I could then solve. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Divide by $x^2$.

Comment: Ohh! Yes I see. I am probably mistaken but I was under the belief that I have to leave it the way as it is or I can't use variation of parameters.

Comment: The point is that $x^2 y'' - 3 x y' + 4 y = x^2/\ln(y)$ is  equivalent to $y'' - 3 y'/x + 4 y/x^2 = 1/\ln(y)$.  The solutions don't know which one you used.

Comment: Yes I got it now. Thank you so much :) .